JMeter doesn't run all iterations
I see that Jmeter doesn't run one iteration on my loop. I count all received messages from test and it indicates on: counter_of_processed 9900. However my run should run 100 users each 100 requests (expected 10 000 messages)
I see something like this in cmd where i run my tests:

That's quite odd because the last run has no Active 100 as previous ones.
Config of loop looks like (i'm passing args when i fire the tests):


We cannot say what's wrong with your configuration without seeing the full test plan.
From what I can see from your screenshots:

Your Thread Group kicks off either 5 threads or the value specified via Users
Your test execution resulted into 20400 samples

So most probably you're using something like Loop Controller or While Controller somewhere in your script and you need to revisit:

its configuration
and the place where you determine your counter_of_processed

A good idea would be increasing JMeter logging verbosity to DEBUG level, this way you will see what exactly is going on under the hood and the reason for JMeter for not entering the last loop iteration.
